# multiple jquery html() assignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the user a "loader" before and during the ajax call. Here's the code (simplified version...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#log").html("loading ajax call...");
        anotherFunc();
    });
});


function anotherFunc(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: correct_url,
       data: data_to_send,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function(data){
        $("#log").html("new html");
       }
   })
}
```

the problem is that "loading ajax call..." never appears. I only see "new html" displayed. the singles ajax #log modification call work perfectly alone (without the other)

is there another way to do?
what am I doing wrong?

ps. I also tryed to write in another id (#log2) with the same result.

Comment: Most likely your `$.ajax` has `async: false`. Change that to `async: true` (or remove it entirely) and it will work.

Comment: Show the stuff inside the `(...)`  Are you sure your ajax call is not completing very quickly?  What browser are you using?  Different browsers render at different speeds and if your ajax call completes really fast then you'll never see the loading string.

Comment: Could it just be that the AJAX call returns so quickly that you just don't see the original text?

Comment: no it's not. the div disappear and appears after the success selector. so jquery has the time to write the loader into the div:log.

browser: firefox/chrome/safari-mobile/safari-desktop

async:true didn't solve

Comment: Then what you are describing doesn't make any sense. The div shouldn't "disappear" unless you tell it to. nothing in the code you have provided should make it disappear.

Comment: sorry, the #log had text before the click...

Comment: Ok, so you click, the log is emptied, the ajax finishes, and then new HTML appears? or what

Comment: yes @KevinB. setting a timeout solves my problem.

Comment: setting a timeout just hides the problem.

Comment: so, what does solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are describing shouldn't be happening. you aren't doing anything that would cause the #log to get emptied, unless it was a synchronous request, but it's not a synchronous request. I mean, if you can live with having a random setTimeout not knowing why it works, go for it.

Comment: of course I would like to know why it doesn't work without the timeout, but the timeout at least displays the "loader"

Comment: @Kevin B `liveLong = function() { live(); setTimeout(liveLong, 0); }; liveLong()` :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely everything works just fine, but the AJAX call returns very quickly (especially if you are testing locally).  To see if that is the case, just do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#log").html("loading ajax call...");
        setTimeout(function(){anotherFunc();},2000);
    });
});
```